# Не работает XDebug в PhpStorm с проектом в VirtualBox по ssh

Tags: ssh, phpstorm, virtualbox, xdebug

Хост - Windows. В виртуальной машине - Ubuntu, и там PHP-проект в Docker-контейнере, адаптер - сетевой мост, доступ из хоста через IP 192.168.0.104. Проект в виртуалке мапится на IP 172.16.100.1 (порт 10443). Через JetBrains Gateway открыл этот проект в хостовой системе (установив в удалённую машину PhpStorm). Всё настроил, результаты этих настроек - на скринах.

[image: Settings PHP]

[image: Settings PHP>Debug]

[image: Settings PHP>Debug>DBGp_Proxy]

[image: Settings PHP>Servers]

Файл xdebug.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.mode=coverage,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=172.16.100.1
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
; xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
; xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Включил XDebug. Поставил в самое начало index.php точку останова. В PowerShell пробрасываю туннель.

ssh -R 9000:localhost:9003 pavel@md.mydomain.local

md.mydomain.local привязан в файле C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts к IP 192.168.0.104.

Захожу в браузере на md.mydomain.local:10443 - удалённый PhpStorm не останавливается и не выводит сообщение типа "... without being paused". Что мне ещё нужно донастроить, чтобы работала отладка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Settings > PHP > Debug]

Проблему удалось решить снятием галочки **Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations** в окне Settings > PHP > Debug